# Subdomain accidentaly got indexed on Google

Tags: google-index, search-results

I have main domain `example.com` and subdomain called `static.example.com` that serves images and other static content. It's once hosted whole domain (`example.com`), but I moved main domain to other server but all files/scripts/software remained on `static.example.com`.

Several days ago, I've noticed that Google indexed it and all of the content is the same as on original domain:

```
example.com/some-page.html
static.example.com/some-page.html
```

How can I remove `static.example.com` indexed pages only (leave images and other static content)? Will this be OK:

1) I've uploaded this *robots.txt*:

```
User-agent: googlebot-image
Disallow: 
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

2) Removed all software/scripts from the site so it's now showing 404. Will 301 redirect be more appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this happen before when running a test.mysite.com subdomain, in that instance I didn't actually need to keep the sub domain so I just deleted it, and it slowly got removed from Google.

What I'd suggest is to make a Google Webmaster Tools profile for the subdomain (separate from the main domain's profile), and then once that's set up go to Google Index > Remove urls (in the side bar) and try removing the pages that you've found indexed.

Again in Webmaster Tools go to 'Crawl > Blocked urls' and see that its reading your robots.txt file correctly; this way you'll be able to see that Google knows to explicitly block your URL.

The only other option I could think of would be to somehow block access to the subdomain to everyone apart from your main site, using `.htaccess` (I'm not sure exactly the process for this, but someone on here should be able to point you in the right direction).